Remove vertical lines from a cell row
I am writing a solution to a permutations question and would like to remove the vertical cell lines adjacent to term 1, term 2, .... term [n - (r-1)].
I've been looking at the multicolumn command, but have had no success.
\begin{equation*}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \underbrace{
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
        \hline
        $n$ & $n - 1$ & $n - 2$ & $n - 3$ & . & . & . & $[n - (r - 2) ]$ &  $[n - (r - 1) ]$ \\
        \hline
        term 1 &  term 2 & term 3 & term 4 & . & . & . & term $r - 1$ &  term $r$ \\    
    \end{tabular}}_{r \;terms}
\end{equation*}

Any help appreciated.

Like this?

With use of the tabularray packages is easy:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \underbrace{
    \begin{tblr}{vline{1-Z}={1}{0.5pt},
                 colspec = { *{9}{c} },
                 row{2} = {mode=text}
                 }
        \hline
n       & n - 1  & n - 2  & n - 3  & . & . & . & [n - (r - 2) ] &  [n - (r - 1) ] \\
    \hline
term 1  & term 2 & term 3 & term 4 & . & . & . & term $r - 1$   &  term $r$ 
    \end{tblr}}_{r \;\mathrm{terms}}
\]
\end{document}


| are the lines. If you want to remove one for a given cell, \multicolumn{1}{c}{<content>} will eliminate the line to the right and/or left, depending on the cell. So
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{<first>} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{<second>} & ... \multicolumn{1}{c|}{<last>} \\

will produce a row with vertical rules to the left of the first cell and the right of the last, but no vertical rules between the cells.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\underbrace{
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{9}{c}}[hvlines,last-row]
$n$ & $n-1$  & $n-2$  & $n-3$  & . & . & . & $[n-(r-2)]$ &  $[n-(r-1)]$ \\
term 1  & term 2 & term 3 & term 4 & . & . & . & term $r - 1$   &  term $r$ 
\end{NiceTabular}}_{r \;\text{terms}}\]

\end{document}



Thank-you.  Great solution.

You can define a local command to ease input:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \newcommand{\?}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{#1}}}
  \underbrace{
    \begin{array}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    n & n - 1 & n - 2 & n - 3 & . & . & . & [n - (r - 2)] &  [n - (r - 1)] \\
    \hline
    \?{term $1$} & \?{term $2$} & \?{term $3$} & \?{term $4$} & \?{.} & \?{.} & \?{.} & 
      \?{term $r-1$} & \?{term $r$} \\    
    \end{array}}_{\text{$r$ terms}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


